# Moxy: XmlInverse and getter/setter different than property name

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I'm working at a place where the convention for member variable is "m_(name)" and the getters and setters are "(get/set)Name".

So, I have:

AccidentName.java

```
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "m_occupants")
public AccidentVehicle getAccidentVehicleRecord() {
    ...
}
```

AccidentVehicle.java

```
@XmlElementWrapper( name="Occupants" )
@XmlElements( @XmlElement( name="AccidentName" ) )
public Set<AccidentName> getOccupants() {
    return m_occupants;
}
```

I'm trying to define inverse references using Moxy's annotation but I'm getting errors like this:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [accidentVehicleRecord] is not defined in the domain class [net.denali.inpursuit.rms.data.persistent.accident.AccidentName], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: accidentVehicleRecord
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLInverseReferenceMapping[accidentVehicleRecord]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(net.denali.inpursuit.rms.data.persistent.accident.AccidentName --> [DatabaseTable(AccidentName), DatabaseTable(AuditableEntity)])
```

The getter/setter is (get/set)AccidentVehicleRecord, but the member variable is m_accidentVehicleRecord.

Do I need to always specify both side of an inverse?
Do I need to have methods name exactly matching pattern get(variable name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to recreate the issue you are seeing.  I have entered a bug here:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/429607

### Work Around

You could switch to use field access.

**AccidentVechicle**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AccidentVehicle {

    @XmlElementWrapper( name="Occupants" )
    @XmlElements( @XmlElement( name="AccidentName" ) )
    private Set<AccidentName> m_occupants = new HashSet<AccidentName>();

    public Set<AccidentName> getOccupants() {
        return m_occupants;
    }

}
```

**AccidentName**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AccidentName {

    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "occupants")
    private AccidentVehicle m_accidentVehicleRecord;

    public AccidentVehicle getAccidentVehicleRecord() {
        return m_accidentVehicleRecord;
    }

}
```

Comment: I actually had field access to begin with, but something about our domain model (excessive inheritance perhaps) was causing the field elements to be skipped when marshaling to XML. Changing to property access has made them all suddenly appear. So this was actually already a workaround to the workaround you propose. :)